# What causes this type of error. No visible @interface for xxxxxx. The root cause. Not just this one

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

**I see there are 869 questions** ranging over many years asking how to fix this error. What I'm trying to understand is the fundamental reason for this message.
Each one of the 869 questions is different. Including this one. I'm updating some code from Apple's Resources **The AVCamera** code, to work with iOS11. Obj-c. 
The line returning this error in this case is

> [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

**However, what I really need** is to understand what the root causes of this error are. Not just in this case, but most cases. 
I first put this project together in 2014, and of course, there have been a dozen updates since then, so there are many Depreciated statements. I have it down to 8 depreciations now, but I have three errors pop up. This has been one of them. Two NO visible interfaces, and one No known class.

```
        //AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    AVCapturePhotoOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc] init];
    if ([session canAddOutput:stillImageOutput])
    {
       // [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG}];
        NSDictionary *outputSettings = @{ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG};
        [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

        [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
        [self setStillImageOutput:stillImageOutput];
    }
});
```

Comment: Apple change APIs sometimes as others do. First they mark some methods or even classes as deprecated: you can still use them but it is not recommended because eventually (usually in few years) the deprecated methods/classes will be removed. 
If you must support the old code, you can either use older SDKs or refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

As in Sergiy's comment, the method that is said to be "NO visible interfaces" and No known class are removed from the iOS 11's SDK.
Apple sometimes do these drastic changes. But generally these methods and classes get marked as deprecated, first and then (after some iOS major updates) they are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand the circumstances behind Apple's decision. As for the code above, I solved it simply by changing the code to this. The redundant code is commented out, and the new code inserted.

However, the fundamental question of "No visible interface" remains a mystery to me. What exactly does it mean?

```
        //AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    AVCapturePhotoOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc] init];
    if ([self.session canAddOutput:stillImageOutput])
    {
        [self.session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
        self.stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput;

       // [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG}];
       // NSDictionary *outputSettings = @{ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG};
       // [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

        //[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
        //[self setStillImageOutput:stillImageOutput];
    }
});
```